# Compound annotation for Junit 5

Tags: java, annotations

I'd like to do something like the following:

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)@Test
@Tag("")
@DisplayName("")
public @interface TaggedTest {
   // ...
}
```

And use that annotation like the following:

```java
@TaggedTest(tag="unitTest", displayName="A custom display name")
public void myMethod() {
   // some code
}
```

I know that's possible when you are using SpringBoot annotations. But how to get the same using any kind of other annotations, like JUnit, JPA or whatever?